# Local Shared Object iOS limits

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I know the usual limits of `SharedObject` are 100kb and 20 objects per site.

Do those limits apply to Adobe Air for mobile too?

Comment: I don't know if there is a limit for Adobe AIR (my guess is it is the same), but you can use `File` and `FileStream` to write your own objects to disk and the only limits imposed on those are file system limits (remaining disk space and a possible 4GB limit depending on system)

Comment: Thanks, I know that. Just want to know what are the limits in Air apps, vs Flash player. I haven't been able to find any reference.